# Read items from list in host-web from provider-hosted app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I have a provider hosted app. and I'm trying to get to the listitems in a list that is on my host-web.

I can get a list of all the lists I have. But when I try to get to the listitems, it's always empty.

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                ListCollection lists = clientContext.Web.Lists;
                List list = lists.GetByTitle("TestList");

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load<ListCollection>(lists);
                clientContext.Load<List>(list);
                clientContext.Load<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection>(items);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in items)
                {
                    Response.Write("<br />" + item.FieldValues["Title"]);
                }
            }
```

In the AppManifest.xml i added a 'full control' permission for list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AppManifest.xml add a **READ permission** for **list** and **Web**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I did everything correct. When installing I still had to say which lists it had full control on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine ....

Just you have to make change in "AppManifest.xml" file permission  give site collection as full control as you are using host web .